# How can I send notifications only to certain users in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, notifications

I have notifications that need to be sent when someone makes a new post. But I need those notifications to be sent only to people that are in that subject.

I made a notification table and I managed to make so notifications would show up for users, but I need to filter it.

These are the relevant tables I'm trying to use:

This is for the posts:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('text');

            $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subjects')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Subjects:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('text');
            $table->unsignedInteger('year');
```

And the standard users and notifications table. So i basically need notifications to be sent to users who are in certain subject. So if a post is made in subject with id=1 notification would be sent to user that has a subject_id=1. For that relation I have this table:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subjects')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

So this connects my user and subject ids.

I tried something like this:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
            if($user->subjects()->id==$subject_id)
            $user->notify(new Notify($subject_id, $obavjestenje));
        }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: can you try `$user->subjects()->where('subject_id', $subject_id)->first()` instead of `$user->subjects()->id==$subject_id`.

Because `$user->subjects()->id` will always return null

Comment: It works, thank you. Do you know how can I make it so the notification doesn't go to the person that made the post?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all users that have subjects and exclude the poster user like this

```
// get all users that have matching subject
$users = User::whereHas('subjects', function($query) use ($subject_id) {
  $query->where('id', '=', $subject_id);
})
// exclude user that created the post
->where('user_id', '<>', $post_user_id)
->get();
```

Where `$post_user_id` is the id of the user that created the post

Then you can send out your notifications

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $user->notify(new Notify($subject_id, $obavjestenje));
}
```